# Request is not available in this context exception when runnig mvc on iis7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5

when i running mvc app on iis7.5 win 7 it cause an exception "Request is not available in this context" which this don't cause when running by vs2008. can anyone help me?

Comment: By any chance, do you access the request object in your global.asax?

Comment: i use Request object for a class that inherit from FilterAttribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answers and notes in my question regarding use of the request object in the global.asax file may be helpful.  Are you developing on a system that doesn't use IIS7 by any chance?

[Global ASAX - get the server name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790457/global-asax-get-the-server-name)