# http module: Request is not available

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating an http module where I want to check if a request is coming from an authenticated  user and redirect to the login page if it's not.

I registered the module in the web.config file and I have the following code that's throwing an exception:

```
public class IsAuthModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Dispose() { }

    public void Init(HttpApplication TheApp)
    {
        var TheRequest = TheApp.Request;

    }
}
```

It throwing an exception that says "Request is not available in this context"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518057/request-is-not-available-in-this-context

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Init stage you have no request in progress. You have to subscribe the event for beginning of a request:

```
public void Init(HttpApplication TheApp)
{
    TheApp.BeginRequest += Application_BeginRequest;

    // End Request handler
    //application.EndRequest += Application_EndRequest;
}

private void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e) 
{
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this nice concise answer, sure beats tutorial-length explanations!