# Check if code is executing inside Application_Start

Tags: asp.net, application-start

Can I check if my exception handler code (registered in `Application_Error`) is running inside of `Application_Start`?  Tn an ASP.NET app in IIS 7 integrated mode there's `RequestContext` inside the `Application_Start` method (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2518066/794234)). Right now I'm using a `Try ... Catch` block to deal with this situation, but if there's a way to check *before* calling `Context.Request` it would be nice (`Try ... Catch` is expensive).

```
Public Sub Application_Error()
    Dim pageName As String

    Try
        pageName = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path
    Catch(ex As Exception)
        pageName = "Inside Application_Start, no page name"
    End Try

    'exception logging co
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the exception you get? A nullreference perhaps, because the `Request` is null?

Comment: No, you get an `HttpException` with the message "Request is not available in this context".