# Why is HttpContext.Current null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, quartz.net, httpcontext

I have a value that I use in all the application; I set this in application_start

```
  void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Dictionary<int, IList<string>> Panels = new Dictionary<int, IList<string>>();
    List<clsPanelSetting> setting = clsPanelSettingFactory.GetAll();
    foreach (clsPanelSetting panel in setting)
    {
        Panels.Add(panel.AdminId, new List<string>() { panel.Phone,panel.UserName,panel.Password});
    }
    Application["Setting"] = Panels;

    SmsSchedule we = new SmsSchedule();
    we.Run();

  }
```

and in SmsSchedule

```
public class SmsSchedule : ISchedule
{
    public void Run()
    {           
        DateTimeOffset startTime = DateBuilder.FutureDate(2, IntervalUnit.Second);
        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<SmsJob>()
            .WithIdentity("job1")
            .Build();

        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
             .WithIdentity("trigger1")
             .StartAt(startTime)
             .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInSeconds(60).RepeatForever())
             .Build();

        ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        IScheduler sc = sf.GetScheduler();
        sc.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

        sc.Start();
    }
}
```

I want to get this value in a class.(smsjob)

```
   public class SmsJob : IJob 
   {  
      public virtual void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
      {
          HttpContext.Current.Application["Setting"]; 
      }
   }
```

but my problem is : HttpContext.Current is null, why is HttpContext.Current null?

**Edit:**
When i use this code in another class of a page it works, but in this class I get the error.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Clearly `HttpContext.Current` is not `null` only if you access it in a thread that handles incoming requests. That's why it works "when i use this code in another class of a page".

It won't work in the scheduling related class because relevant code is not executed on a valid thread, but a background thread, which has no HTTP context associated with.

Overall, don't use `Application["Setting"]` to store global stuffs, as they are not global as you discovered.

If you need to pass certain information down to business logic layer, pass as arguments to the related methods. Don't let your business logic layer access things like `HttpContext` or `Application["Settings"]`, as that violates the principles of isolation and decoupling.

Update:
Due to the introduction of `async/await` it is more often that such issues happen, so you might consider the following tip,

In general, you should only call `HttpContext.Current` in only a few scenarios (within an HTTP module for example). In all other cases, you should use

- `Page.Context` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.context?view=netframework-4.7.2
- `Controller.HttpContext` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.httpcontext?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

instead of `HttpContext.Current`.

Comment: Also, have in mind that when using the keywords `async/await`, lines that follow an `await` are not neccessarily the same thread that handles the incoming request. Reference `HttpContext.Current` before your first `await` to be sure to avoid a `NullReferenceException` (I have sen functions where it works, other where it doesn't, so being consistent is key)

Comment: @Lex Li But won't storing Session in a Singleton class have all Users to share same session

Comment: Is there any solution Lex? I'd like to access current user in a class library.

Comment: @Lex Li what is your suggestion?

Comment: @Lex Li Be more to the point. You use unnecessarily colorful language and it's obscuring your answer.

Comment: @Lex Li. How u solve this when u have a component that register user actions across multiple module and u want a single Id to record this information and have a trace? Asuming of coruse we have controllers and threads. Regards

Answer (score 7):

In IIS7 with integrated mode, `Current` is not available in `Application_Start`. There is a similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518057/request-is-not-available-in-this-context).

Answer (score 6):

try to implement `Application_AuthenticateRequest` instead of `Application_Start`.

this method has an instance for `HttpContext.Current`, unlike `Application_Start` (which fires very soon in app lifecycle, soon enough to not hold a `HttpContext.Current` object yet).

hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but when i use this code in another class i get value, but in a this class `HttpContext.Current` is null.

Comment: as i said, it all is being called from `Application_Start`. move it under `Application_AuthenticateRequest` in global.asax and it will work!

Comment: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' for `HttpContext.Current`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39711/discussion-between-gal-v-and-ar-gorgin)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using an asp.net webforms application, try to add this line in your web.config, it might work for you:

```
  <appSettings>
   <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is WCF service you can add following in your web.config.

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

A Boolean value indicating whether the ASP.NET compatibility mode has been turned on for the current application. The default is `false`.

When this attribute is set to `true`, requests to Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) services flow through the ASP.NET HTTP pipeline, and communication over non-HTTP protocols is prohibited.

Answer (score 0):

System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/File");
You can solve your problem by using.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35299528)