# HttpContext.Current is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am using the below code to remove the a particular cookies.It's worked earlier. But it's not working now. Got error  HttpContext.Current is null. I can't guess why it's happen now. Please clarify me.

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[name] != null{
  HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Remove(name);
}
```

Please help me fix this.

Comment: did you test your application on localhost, or external IIS server?

Comment: localhost and server also

Comment: got the same error in both localhost and server

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509672/why-httpcontext-current-be-null

Comment: Where is this code placed? For example, are you in a global.asax hook method?

Comment: My code placed inside common.cs file. And call this function using an object.

Answer (score -1):

try this.

```
 HttpCookieCollection MyCookieCollection = Request.Cookies;
 HttpCookie MyCookie = MyCookieCollection.Get(name);
 if ( MyCookie != null)
 {
     HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Remove(name);
 }
```

Comment: I got the error.  Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: try again i made few changes.