# Object Reference error for User.Identity.Name in MVC 5 Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I want to get the UserName of the currently logged in User. But when I used **User.Identity.Name** I got following error:

> System.NullReferenceException. Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.

The code where I am getting the error is as follows:

```
UsersConfigurationController qr = new UsersConfigurationController();
        public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                context.Roles.Add(new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole()
                {
                    Name = collection["RoleName"]
                });
                context.SaveChanges();
                qr.singleRoleAddToDb(collection["RoleName"]);
                ViewBag.ResultMessage = "Role created successfully !";
                return RedirectToAction("Create");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

The error occurs when the following line is executed:

> qr.singleRoleAddToDb(collection["RoleName"]);

The function **singleRoleAddToDb** resides in UserConfigurationController as follows:

```
public void singleRoleAddToDb(string rolename)
        {
            UserRoles urls = new UserRoles();
            urls.S1 = rolename;
            urls.S2 = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
            urls.N102 = db.Users.Where(x => x.S1 == HttpContext.User.Identity.Name).Single().N102;
            db.UserRoles.Add(urls);
            db.SaveChanges();

        }
```

As soon as the line **urls.S2 = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;** executes the debugger switches to Catch statement and throws the above mentioned erro.
I have already tried to change the authentication mode in config file:

```
<authentication mode="Forms" />
```

and also

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

But the error continues.

Comment: @DanielKelley, I know about this error.. But here I am unable to get the point why this error is occurring for User.Identity.Name

Comment: Why not using UserManager to get UserName of Logged in user?

Comment: set your breakpoints, and see where the error is thrown.

Comment: Which property is `null`? `HttpContext` or `User` or `Identity`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Name is empty..

Comment: @user1666620, when setting the property urls.S2 = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

Comment: The `Name` being empty (`null`) will NOT throw an exception. Either `HttpContext` or `User` or `Identity` is `null` - debug your code

Comment: As a sanity check - is the user actually logged in when this method is called?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, kindly see this image.. it has the screenshot for my identity property in debugging mode. [link](http://imgur.com/Sx0ZkSn)

Comment: @Shaamaan, User is obviously logged in.. That would be the first thing I would check. and I already did. The application is saying Hello to the user after successful logging in

Comment: @AwaisMahmood Looking at your screenshot - first, the user isn't logged  in (`IsAuthenticated` is false), but `HttpContext.User.Identity` isn't null and `Name` is just an empty string. Then I suspect your `db` object might not exist. `db` is not assigned anywhere the code you've shown, so it's difficult to say if that's the problem or not.

Comment: @AwaisMahmood, You have shown an image that is not the same as the code in your question. `urls.S2 = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;` cannot throw an exception just because `Name` is an empty string.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, check the edit.. Sorry for not mentioning the complete code. I thought that it wont be needed.

Comment: Looking at the question after the edit - something doesn't add up. In your screenshot `HttpContext.User.Identity` isn't null and `Name` is an empty string. But you say the error is thrown on `urls.S2 = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;`, and `urls` has just been created. Either for some strange reason `HttpContext` isn't *kept* between functions, or you're looking at wrong code (this can happen if you're looking at newer code than was used in the DLLs loaded by IIS).

Comment: What does `string name = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;` return? Is property `S2` of `UserRoles` a simple get/set or is there some code in the setter?

Comment: Can you post complete exception stacktrace? `db.Users.Where(x => x.S1 == HttpContext.User.Identity.Name)`  might returning empty collection, so `.Single().N102` throw exception.

Comment: @Mark Unless `Users` is null, then `Single` won't throw a null-reference error. `Single` will inform if the collection contains no elements or too many elements in a more informative manner.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, simple get/set.. Actually, when debugger reaches at line **urls.S2 = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;**, it jumps to the **Catch** block. So, I cannot see which is null

Comment: @Mak, when debugger reaches at line urls.S2 = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;, it jumps to the Catch block. so the error whatever causing it, occurs before db execution

Comment: Can you add more code to the application and see what happens? Add the following to the start of `singleRoleAddToDb`: `if (HttpContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("HttpContext"); if (HttpContext.User == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("HttpContext.User"); if (HttpContext.User.Identity == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("HttpContext.User.Identity");` and so on as needed... Do that, and you should get better indication of what is null.

Comment: @AwaisMahmood, Just add `string name = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;` before the `try` block and inspect the values

Comment: @Shaamaan, when I added your mentioned codes at start of **singleRoleAddToDb** it is observed that **HttpContext** is null in that controller.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, when I added user.identity.name before try block, it successfully gets the user name.. But in the other controller where **singleAddToDb** resides **HttpContext** is null

Comment: Well, there's your answer then. Modify the method to accept the identity as a parameter, and pass that where needed. `public void singleRoleAddToDb(string rolename, string identityName) {...}`

Comment: @StephenMuecke,  Thank you very much for this long discussion. But can you tell why HttpContext is null in the other controller???. Thanks again

Comment: Without looking at your entire code I cannot tell. If I were to make a wild guess it would be because it's called from a different DLL and might simply not have access to `HttpContext`. But, again, wild guessing here!

Comment: Are your saying the `Create()` and `singleRoleAddToDb()` methods are in separate controllers? If so then of course `HttpContext.User` will be `null`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Yes, they are in different controllers.. But isn't the **HttpContext** values available in entire application? I mean if I want to get UserName in any other controller I can simply get it by **HttpContext**

Comment: @Shaamaan, all the controllers are called from 1 DLL... So, How can the DLL is different??

Comment: Well, a quick Google shows [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509672/why-httpcontext-current-be-null) result. I don't know if it's relevant here or not.

Comment: No they are not. The `HttpContext` is generated from the request, and `User` properties from its `cookies` (which don't exist in your other controller because its not called from a request)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, THANKS a lot man, You really solved my problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for some reason you cannot use a debugger to catch the code and inspect the variables you can try this old trick...

Add the following code to the start of `singleRoleAddToDb` method to check what exactly is null:

```
if (HttpContext == null) 
  throw new ArgumentNullException("HttpContext");
if (HttpContext.User == null) 
  throw new ArgumentNullException("HttpContext.User"); 
if (HttpContext.User.Identity == null) 
  throw new ArgumentNullException("HttpContext.User.Identity");
```

Depending on what turns out to be missing you may need to pass that as an additional parameter.

Comment: This helped me in finding an answer.. Actually HttpContext was null because singleRoleAddToDb method was not called from the user request