# Error when sending email using postal MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, quartz.net, postal

**Requirement:**

Send emails to all users dynamically everyday at a particular time, say 6:00 AM.

**What I did so far:**

I use a third party library called Quartz.net from Nuget.

```
public class TaskScheduler : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        try {
            UserRepository userRepo = new UserRepository();
            var users = userRepo.GetUsers();

            DashBoardRepository repo = new DashBoardRepository();
            foreach (var rec in users)
            {
                var tasks = repo.GetIncompleteTasks(rec.UserID);
                var appointments = repo.GetUpcomingAppointments(rec.UserID);

                if (tasks.Count > 0 || appointments.Count > 0)
                {
                    dynamic email = new Email("TaskEmail");
                    email.To = rec.Email;
                    email.From = "no-reply@xyz.com";
                    email.Subject = "Pending items in XYZ";
                    email.Tasks = tasks;
                    email.Appointments = appointments;
                    email.Send();
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            clsLog.LogMessageToFile(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}

public static class JobScheduler
{
    public static void Start()
    {
        IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
        scheduler.Start();

        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<TaskScheduler>().Build();

        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule
              (s =>
                s.WithIntervalInHours(24)
                .OnEveryDay()
                .StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(6, 0))
              )
            .Build();

        scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }
}

protected void Application_Start()
    {           
        JobScheduler.Start();
    }
```

I am using Postal in MVC to send the email.

This works fine in my local if I run from my Visual Studio. But once I deploy it onto IIS, I get the error below:

```
   System.ArgumentException: The virtual path '/' maps to another application, which is not allowed.
   at System.Web.CachedPathData.GetVirtualPathData(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean permitPathsOutsideApp)
   at System.Web.HttpContext.GetFilePathData()
    -------------
```

I am hosting this application as a sub directory in the IIS. So it is something like http://www.maindemosite.com/xyz

[image]

**Web.Config:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5v361934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-XYZ-201405202911.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-XYZ-20140534102911;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="XYZEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DAL.XYZEntities.csdl|res://*/DAL.XYZEntities.ssdl|res://*/DAL.XYZEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=SERVER\MSSQL;initial catalog=XYZTest;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="AuthenticationSlide" value="100" />
    <add key="DocumentsPath" value="C:/Users/KKK/Documents/Documents/" />
    <add key="XYZDeployment" value="http://localhost:51641" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>
      <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" name="ABCAuthorization" />
    </federationConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel.services>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp>
        <network host="smtp.ABC.com" port="25" userName="xxx@xxx.ca" password="!@abc99" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
  <system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
      <securityTokenHandlers>
        <remove type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <add type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Tokens.MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </securityTokenHandlers>
    </identityConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="1" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="1048576" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    </modules>
  <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers></system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.0.0" newVersion="2.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Practices.Unity" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings />
    <client />
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**Complete Error Message:**

```
    Log Entry : 10:09:40 AM Friday, October 14, 2016
  :
  :System.ArgumentException: The virtual path '/' maps to another application, which is not allowed.
   at System.Web.CachedPathData.GetVirtualPathData(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean permitPathsOutsideApp)
   at System.Web.HttpContext.GetFilePathData()
   at System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig.GetConfig(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Configuration.HttpCapabilitiesBase.GetBrowserCapabilities(HttpRequest request)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Browser()
   at System.Web.HttpRequestWrapper.get_Browser()
   at System.Web.WebPages.BrowserHelpers.GetOverriddenBrowser(HttpContextBase httpContext, Func`2 createBrowser)
   at System.Web.WebPages.DisplayModeProvider.<.ctor>b__2(HttpContextBase context)
   at System.Web.WebPages.DisplayModeProvider.<GetAvailableDisplayModesForContext>d__4.MoveNext()
   at System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.GetPath(ControllerContext controllerContext, String[] locations, String[] areaLocations, String locationsPropertyName, String name, String controllerName, String cacheKeyPrefix, Boolean useCache, String[]& searchedLocations)
   at System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String viewName, String masterName, Boolean useCache)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.<>c__DisplayClass6.<FindView>b__4(IViewEngine e)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.Find(Func`2 lookup, Boolean trackSearchedPaths)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String viewName, String masterName)
   at Postal.EmailViewRenderer.CreateView(String viewName, ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Postal.EmailViewRenderer.Render(Email email, String viewName)
   at Postal.EmailService.Send(Email email)
   at XYZ.Utilities.TaskScheduler.Execute(IJobExecutionContext context) in D:\Applications\XYZ\Utilities\TaskScheduler.cs:line 33
```

Comment: Please post your web.config

Comment: Posted web.config

Comment: Try to change C:/Users/KKK/Documents/Documents/ to a directory on application path or check if access already exists to iis user.

Comment: But this path has nothing to do with sending email

Comment: Please send the url that you are getting this exception, the problem could be on the page accessed.

Comment: why you are not using VBS Script for this ?

Comment: Is your template file located at "Views\Emails\TaskEmail.cshtml" ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this issue: [Postal Issue #65](https://github.com/andrewdavey/postal/issues/65), it seems that you have `HttpContext.Current` contains null value when trying to get relative path of your project root directory in IIS deployment server. Here was the checklist to do:

1. Try moving `JobScheduler.Start()` method from `Application_Start` to `Application_AuthenticateRequest` method call during application startup. AFAIK, the `Application_Start` method doesn't contain `HttpContext.Current` instance as `Application_AuthenticateRequest` has.

   ```
   protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest()
   {
       JobScheduler.Start();
   }
   ```
2. Check if your IIS deployment server setting set to integrated mode. In this mode Application_Start doesn't contain `HttpContext.Current` due to design changes on integrated pipeline. As Mike Volodarsky said:

> Basically, if you happen to be accessing the request context in
>   `Application_Start`, you have two choices:
>
> 1. Change your application code to not use the request context (recommended).
> 2. Move the application to Classic mode (NOT recommended).

The first choice means it was some alternatives beside `Application_AuthenticateRequest`, which uses `Application_BeginRequest` or any other event methods that includes `HttpContext.Current` instance.

3. If absolute path was used, check if it is exist on deployment server. The relative path is more preferred in web.config file, thus you may change paths like this:

   ```
   <add key="DocumentsPath" value="~/Documents/Documents/" />
   ```

Afterwards, ensure `Application_Start` method doesn't contain any other method that contains `HttpContext.Current` instance, including database context if any.

References:

[Why is HttpContext.Current null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509672/why-is-httpcontext-current-null)

[IIS7 Integrated mode: Request is not available in this context exception in Application_Start](http://mvolo.com/iis7-integrated-mode-request-is-not-available-in-this-context-exception-in-applicationstart/)

Related problem:

[Request is not available in this context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518057/request-is-not-available-in-this-context)