# why httpcontext object is not available while using task parallel library task?

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library

I am using TPL to create new tasks in my code. All works well with improved performance. but whenever there is HTTPContext object like context.currentuser.iDentifier. this code throws an exception saying HTTP Context object not available. Null reference exception.
I want to know how to pass the context object to the task object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: HttpContext.Current is not null only if you access it in a thread that handles incoming requests. With TPL you code can be executed in different thread. Details - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509672/why-is-httpcontext-current-null

Comment: @rene, this is not duplicate. the question you referred to is generic .NET framework null reference exception.

Comment: It is a perfect duplicate. This error is so common, we are not going to debug every single occurrence of it. Specially if you don't have an [MCVE].

Comment: I am not asking to debug. I just wanted to know why this occurs and how to pass context object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the parallel thread is not executing in the same context. You need to pass the [SynchronizationContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) it.
In TPL you can use `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` to pass the context.

In one of my project I have done it something like this -

```
 Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MyMethod(),
                          CancellationToken.None,
                          TaskCreationOptions.None, 
                          TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```