# Global.asax Application_Start Get Action Url / RedirectToAction?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, routes, global-asax

On application start I am checking app versions from the assembly against a value stored in the web.config. If the versions differ, I want to trigger the default installer.

So I need to get an Action route. But this doesn't seem possible to do as the HttpContext is null? I have an Action called "Install" in my "HomeController"

Any ideas how I can get a RedirectToAction or similar to work from the Application_Start ?

Answer (score 0):

You wont have access to Request in application start, as [per IIS blog](http://mvolo.com/iis7-integrated-mode-request-is-not-available-in-this-context-exception-in-applicationstart).

Ramifications of this have been discussed on SO before

[Global ASAX - get the server name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790457/global-asax-get-the-server-name)

[Request is not available in this context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518057/request-is-not-available-in-this-context)

For you case, could you not call the installation code directly from global without having to go to the action?