# "System.Web.HttpException: Response is not available in this context" only in IIS

Tags: c#, iis, response, global-asax, httpcontext

i have used the `Http.Current.Response` in my global.asax.cs Application Start. It is working fine without any issue when i execute in my PC. How ever when i try to put it in IIS with Windows Server 2008 R2, i find that it is giving the following error.[image]

the code for it is

```
public static void SetCookie(string key, string value, int dayExpires)
    {
        HttpCookie encodedCookie = HttpSecureCookie.Encode(new HttpCookie(key, value));
        encodedCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(dayExpires);

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Remove(key);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(encodedCookie);
    }
```

I wanted to trace out why it is getting executed in my system, but not in IIS.

Thanks

Comment: it is called in Application_Start()

Answer (score 4):

I would not do request/response oriented things in Application_Start. Try doing it in `BeginRequest`.

Answer (score 3):

The request context is not available in application start when running in integrated mode in IIS7.

Please see my question and the accepted answer here for details:

[Global ASAX - get the server name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790457/global-asax-get-the-server-name)

---

Would also note that there seems to be a logical bug in your code - this will set the cookie only for the person that hits the site when the application starts - this will not run for every request, or every session.