# WCF Global.asax events not firing

Tags: wcf, global-asax

I have built a WCF application which has Global.asax file. I have added AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)
on top of service class and added
    
into web.config as well.
Global.asax Application_Start event fires when debugging the application but when it deployed in the IIS7 its not firing.

Any help or idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a request to your app does the "Application_Start" fire then?  I don't believe it will be started until the first request is made.

Application level events only need proper naming to work. Is your codebehind class being designated in your Global.asax file?

```
 <%@ Application Inherits="YourNamespace.YourApplicationClass" Language="C#" %>
```

**(Or)**

becuase project is compiled first and then you have add or modify or changed location of global.asax.cs.

Solution :- Just remove debug folder. Clean project and then rebuild whole project.

**Edit**

When using the response object from an aspx page, its codebehind class or a
user control, the response object is directly available because all these
derive from the page object.

When using the response object in your own class, the object is not
available, but you can access it:

HttpContext.Current.Response. -> something

Take a look at here

[Global ASAX - get the server name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790457/global-asax-get-the-server-name)

Comment: Thank you. But the global.asax file is physically available on the server.

Comment: I'm sorry its firing. It throws an exception 'Response is not available in this context'. It has Request.GetResponse in the code. Why response not exists in global.asax?

Comment: I think you are using response object in your own class. This object will not be available there.

Try using like this
eg:
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Account/Dashboard.aspx");

Comment: I'm not doing any redirection I'm just calling a web service and tring to obtain the response. But still Response is available in the debug mode.

Comment: You don't need to redirect.I just gave for example. in your case replace response with  HttpContext.Current.Response

Comment: I added new REST call instead of App start event. Thanks a lot for all your help