# HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages returning null (nothing) in Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am using this call to get the userlanguages of a browser in asp.net

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages
```

It worked fine for years, but now this request is always null on Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge. It still works on other browsers like Google Chrome, Firefox..

Any solutions?

Comment: Try setting UICulture and Culture on the page directive and what is the result of HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages in google chrome?.

Comment: i tried the same in php
http://www.alphamedia.co.at/Test/

there you see the results

Comment: en-US,en;q=0.8 is the result from the above link.Looks you have got the result. Didn't you?

Comment: on chrome i get "de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,es;q=0.2,fr;q=0.2,af;q=0.2", in internet explorer it's empty

Comment: Have a look at it ,it may help.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790457/global-asax-get-the-server-name